# How to copy gym environment?

Tags: python, copy, openai-gym

**Info:** I am using OpenAI Gym to create RL environments but need multiple copies of an environment for something I am doing. I do not want to do anything like `[gym.make(...) for i in range(2)]` to make a new environment.

**Question:** Given one gym env what is the best way to make a copy of it so that you have 2 duplicate but disconnected envs?

Here is an example:

```
import gym

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
new_env = # NEED COPY OF ENV HERE

env.reset() # Should not alter new_env
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Astariul has an updated answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72281999/14301086):

Their answer states:

```py
import copy 
env_2 = copy.deepcopy(env)
```

For more info about 'copy.deepcopy', and the copy library

[Link to copy library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Oh, you are right. I just assumed that wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: This answer seems deprecated, when I run `env.copy()` I receive the following error :

`'CartPoleEnv' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: Updated! Thanks for notifying me. I don't know too much about this forum, but if there is a way to transfer the 'correct answer' then sending the check to your answer would be good. Also, the first thing in my new answer was a link to yours. Also, would you mind adding a link to the docs for your answer—I know some people (like me, and you) want to take a look at more details regarding the library. [Link to copy docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).
Anyways thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: Hey thanks for the update :)

Yep it's a great idea to add a link to the doc, will do !

Choosing the accepted answer is OP's responsibility !

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to copy the current environment :

```
import gym
import copy

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
env.reset()

env_2 = copy.deepcopy(env)

env.step() # Stepping through `env` will not alter `env_2`
```

---

However note that this solution might not work in case of custom environment, if it contains things that can't be deepcopied (like generators).